# Go back to the Vim 7.4 version?

Tags: vim

I've recently updated Vim in order to use the 8.0 version, but now I'd like to go back to the 7.4 version. I've noticed that there are 2 directories in /usr/share/vim: vim74 and vim80. 
Is there a way to easily shift back from the 8.0 to the 7.4 version ?

Thanks

(Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: how did you install Vim 8? The default version in 16.04 is 7.4, so if you added a PPA for Vim 8, you only need to use `ppa-purge`

Comment: Add the output of `update-alternatives --display vim`. Maybe one of those Vim commands will be the 7.4 version.